# Locally Lipschitz, boundary

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about domains of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I am reading *A First Course in Sobolev Spaces* by Giovanni Leoni. 
This book introduces the following concept to describe the regularity of the boundary of a domain.

(Definition 12.9 in Leoni's book) The boundary $\partial \Omega$ of an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is $locally $ $Lipschitz$ if for each $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$ there exist a neighborhood $A$ of $x_0$, local coordinates $y=(y',y_N) \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \times \mathbb{R}$, with $y=0$ at $x=x_0$, a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $r>0$, such that
\begin{equation*}
\Omega \cap A=\{(y',y_N) \in \Omega \cap A: y' \in Q(0,r), y_N>f(y') \},
\end{equation*}
where $Q(0,r)$ is the open ball centered at the origin with radius $r>0$.

**My question**

In the above definition, $f$ and $r>0$ depend on $x_0$. Therefore, we should write $f=f_{x_0}$, $r=r_{x_0}$.

**Can we show the following?**

Let $K \subset \partial \Omega$ be a compact subset. Then, $\inf_{x_0 \in K}r_{x_0}>0$ and there exists a positive number $M$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{x_0 \in K}\text{Lip}(f_{x_0})\le M,
\end{equation*}
where $\text{Lip}(f)$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$.

I think this holds. But I couldn't prove... If you have a nice idea, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**ADD**

That is, I want to prove the following:

There exist positive numbers $r_K$ and $L_{K}$ such that
for each $x_0 \in K$ there exist a neighborhood $A$ of $x_0$, local coordinates $y=(y',y_N) \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1} \times \mathbb{R}$, with $y=0$ at $x=x_0$, a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}^{N-1} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\text{Lip}(f) \le L_{K}$ and 
\begin{equation*}
\Omega \cap A=\{(y',y_N) \in \Omega \cap A: y' \in Q(0,r_K), y_N>f(y') \},
\end{equation*}
where $Q(0,r_K)$ is the open ball centered at the origin with radius $r_K>0$.

Comment: Who is to say that r is necessarily a continuous function of $x_0$?

Comment: You mean we need additional assumptions to show $\inf_{x_{0} \in K}r_{x_0}>0$?

Comment: Just saying that $K$ is compact does not imply that every function on it attains its infimum. The function needs to have some amount of regularity for that.

Comment: Do you have an example of locally Lipschitz domain which does not satisfy $\inf_{x_0}r_{x_0}>0$?

Comment: I think domains which have smooth boundary satisfy the conditions $\inf_{x \in K}r_x$ and $\sup_{x \in K} \text{Lip}(f_{x_0})$ \le M.

Comment: My point is not to say that you are wrong (I suspect you are right in fact) but that it is not "free", you should try to argue that $r$ has some amount of continuity to it (lower semicontinuity would be enough).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every point $x_0\in K$ you have an open neighborhood $A_{x_0}$ that contains $x_0$. Hence $K\subset\cup_{x_0\in K}A_{x_0}$ and so by compactness you can find $n_K$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_{n_K}\in K$ such that $K\subset\cup_{i=1}^{n_K} A_{x_i}$. So now take $L_K=\max_{i=1,\ldots,{n_K}} L_{x_i}$ and $r_K=\min_{i=1,\ldots,{n_K}}$.
If $x\in K$ then there exists $i\in\{1,\ldots,{n_K}\}$ such that $x\in A_{x_i}$.

**EDIT** Instead of working with cubes use balls (it does not make any difference). For each $x_0\in K$ find a ball $A_{x_0}=B(x_0,r_{x_0})$.  Hence $K\subset\cup_{x_0\in K}B(x_0,\frac{r_{x_0}}2)$ and so by compactness you can find $n_K$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_{n_K}\in K$ such that $K\subset\cup_{i=1}^{n_K} B(x_i,\frac{r_{x_i}}2)$. So now take $L_K=\max_{i=1,\ldots,{n_K}} L_{x_i}$ and $r_K=\min_{i=1,\ldots,{n_K}}\frac{r_{x_i}}2$.
If $x_0\in K$ then there exists $i\in\{1,\ldots,{n_K}\}$ such that $x_0\in B(x_i,\frac{r_{x_i}}2)$. Then $B(x_0,r_{K}) \subset B(x_i,r_{x_i})$. You can take as function $f$ the function $f_{x_i}$ but you will need to make a translation to change the origin into $x_0$.
You can use the same idea with cubes, it is just more cumbersome to write down.

Comment: How about $\inf_{x \in K}r_x>0$?

Comment: You can do the same. Just take $r_K=\min_{i=1,\dots,n}r_{x_i}>0$.

Comment: I cannot understand that it is proof. Please give me a proof.

Comment: I just edited it. Since you can cover $K$ with only finitely many $A_{x_i}$ for each $x_0\in K$ you must be in one of these finitely many $A_{x_i}$ .

Comment: Let $x_0 \in K$. From your argument, there exists a $i=1,\ldots,n$ such that $x_0 \in A_{x_i}$. Therefore, there exists a local coordinates $y=(y',y^N)$ with $y=0$ at $x=x_i$, a Lipschitz function $f$ such that $\Omega \cap A_{x_i}=\{(y',y^N) \in \Omega \cap A_{x_i}: y'\in Q(0,r_{x_i}), y^N >f(y')\}$.

Comment: This is not a proof I want.

Comment: We should prove the following: For any $x_0 \in K$, there exist a neighborhood $A_{x_{0}}$, a local coordinates $y=(y',y^N)$ with $y=0$ at $x=x_0$, a Lipschitz function $f$ with $\text{Lip}(f)\le L_K$ such that $\Omega \cap A_{x_0}=\{(y',y^N) \in \Omega \cap A_{x_0}: y'\in Q(0,r_{K}), y^N >f(y')\}$.

Comment: I'm asking how to prove this

Comment: I just replied.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your polite and thorough response. I understood.